# How to remove background color of a checkbox in java

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

when I run this code it runs error.

```
        Checkbox term3 = new Checkbox("SENG 12213 - Data Structures and Algorithms");
        term3.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,13));
        term3.setSize(300,20);
        term3.setLocation(50,310);
        term3.setOpaque(false);
```

when I run this code, the error is

> cannot resolve the method'setOpaque(Boolen)'

how can I remove this background color,help me with this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrGQM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I run this code, the error is 'cannot resolve the method'setOpaque(Boolen)'

`Checkbox` is an AWT component.

The `setOpaque(…)` method is a Swing method so you need to use a Swing component.

Use a `JCheckBox`.